# How to trigger mousedown event on fabricjs canvas object?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have an image object on a canvas fabricJs and i would like to trigger a mousedown(click) event. Here is what i have tried but it seems not to be working a desired.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('gameCanvas', {selection: false});
 let myImg;
 
 fabric.Image.fromURL('http://placekitten.com/50/50', function(img) 
 {
   myImg = img.set({
                    left: 50, 
                    top: 50 ,
                    width:50,
                    height:50
                  });
                  
   canvas.add(myImg); 
    
   myImg.on('mousedown', function(e)
   {
      console.log('image click event was simulated at: ', e.clientX, e.clientY);
   
   });
 
 });
 
 document.getElementById('triggerBtn').addEventListener('click', function()
 {
    canvas.trigger('mouse:down', {
          objCanvas: myImg,
          objCanvasX: myImg.left,
          objCanvasY: myImg.top
    });
 });
 
 canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
 
      if(e.objCanvas)
      {
      
        if(e.objCanvas.type === 'image')
        {
            e.objCanvas.trigger('mousedown', {
                   clientX: e.objCanvasX,
                   clientY: e.objCanvasY 
            });
        }
      }
      
      else {
        console.log('image was clicked');
      }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
<button id="triggerBtn">Trigger</button>
```

I found the solution to my problem, please refer to the updated snippets

Comment: A canvas does not contain separate objects. Even after you draw images or shapes on it, it’s still just one big canvas without child objects.

Comment: If you want to know if a mouseclick is within the image area you will have to compare the x y coordinates of the click event with the image coordinates. To make this easier you can use a library like Pixi.js

Comment: @Kokodoko. I thought the same as you, but it just means that you haven't studied up on fabric.js either. They build that in for you. http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2#events

Comment: @Xris. Do I understand correctly that you want to trigger a mouseclick on the image by clicking the button, not the image? Presently your code already works by clicking the image itself.

Comment: @Aunt Jemima sorry you are right! I didn’t notice you were already using fabricjs

Comment: I am getting the point, but with the function inside canvas.on('object:mousedown') i am supposed to fire the click event of the target object but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Aunt Jemima . I a trying to simulate a trigger event in my game when another object on canvas touches the image

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my question is in the updated snippet

Comment: Just keep in mind that no internal fabric.js logic gets triggered when you fire events like that. I.e. you don't trigger selections, transforms, etc.